# Application run In Intellij IDEA but give error while Running through Tomcat server

Tags: tomcat, grails, groovy, server, internal-server-error

I'm working with JDK 1.8.0; JRE 1.8.0; Grails 3.3.0; Groovy 2.4.12; Tomcat 8.5; Intellij IDEA.

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name '/error' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1266)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1041)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:984)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:77)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:123)
    org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.forwardToErrorPage(ErrorPageFilter.java:197)
    org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.handleException(ErrorPageFilter.java:180)
    org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:145)
    org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:66)
    org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:123)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure.  It looks like you have an action called "error" in your controller but you don't have a view called "error".  So, you are missing the error.gsp file in your view folder.